# Condensing Mercurial revision history

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We have 2,700+ revisions and it takes a good 30-45 seconds to load Mercurial when doing a merge, push or anything else with TortoiseHg.  I'm wondering if there's a way other than straight up creating a new repository to clean up the revision history.  Say, cut off files under revision 2,400 or so.

Comment: Assuming this GUI is TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer to your question, but:

Maybe reducing "log batch size" to 100 (default is 500) in the settings helps.

Our 2300+ rev repo loads in 2-3 secs (off my 15k rpm SAS-disk, but never mind that), so I don't think your problem is many revs, really. There are much bigger repos out there. :)

Note that both Mercurial core and TortoiseHg developers are keen on finding performance bugs, so it might be worthwhile to ask on the mail-lists for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension to compress several changesets into one. Executing the histedit command on a range of revisions will spawn a text document that looks like this (from the histedit documentation):

> pick c561b4e977df Add beta
>   pick 030b686bedc4 Add gamma
>   pick 7c2fd3b9020c Add delta
>
> Edit history between c561b4e977df and 7c2fd3b9020c
>
> Commands:
>   p, pick = use commit
>   e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
>   **f, fold = use commit, but fold into previous commit**
>   d, drop = remove commit from history

Changing `pick` to `fold` for a certain changeset in the list above will fold it into the previous changeset. It will give you an opportunity to resolve failed merges and enter a new commit message as well.

### WARNING:

Using histedit will modify the repository history, including hash IDs, which will cause problems unless you re-start each developer with a new repository clone after the changes have been made. Also, you would probably need to limit your histedit-ing to changesets with a single parent (ie: non-merge changesets).